# Plotting with Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot

i have the following dataframe: 
[image]

But i have no idea how to plot it, so it can look like this one: 
[image]

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please, do not share images of the data you are working on. It makes it extremely hard to help you. Post the data instead.

Comment: We cannot answer your question if you didnt provide code [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] maybe can help

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is a preprocessed dataframe, so it is kind of difficult to give you the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing was the following:
1.- Use the df.values() function to get it in an array, then, reshape it some way that i know the columns have the values of each state.
2.-Create a dictionary, the values are array slices and the keys the name for each state.

```
vals = cu.values.reshape(4,11)
plotdict = {}
for i, estado in enumerate(entidades):
    plotdict[estado] = vals[:,i-1]
for estado, datos in plotdict.items():
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4], datos, label=estado, c=np.random.rand(3,))
    plt.yscale(value="log")
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))
    plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4], ['Q1', 'Q2','Q3','Q4'])
```

[image]